# Yii2 - How to securely store and access sensitive data across user session

Tags: php, security, yii2, session-variables

The database in my PHP Yii2 framework based web application is encrypted and I will be generating the encryption key based off the user password. Is there a secure way to store this in the memory so that it can be used when required?

I believe saving it as a sessions variable will get it written to the disk and perhaps I may want to avoid that.

Comment: By user password, I hope you mean password hash. Sessions are pretty safe. If your sessions are exposed, there are a lot bigger issues than this. You could also save that in memory via Redis or Memcached or in a different database, but technically, those are on disk (Memcached being an exception, RAM only, no disk dump) as well.

Comment: @Ravenous I meant that the user's password will be used to generate a key (PBKDF2) and then that key will be stored in session.